# expect object to receive method in a controller using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to test if a method is called when an action of a controller is called.

```
describe Admin::CartProductDesignsController, :type => :controller do
  let!(:personalized_cart_product) { create :personalized_cart_product}
  let!(:cart_product_design) { create :cart_product_design, quantity: 100, personalized_cart_product: personalized_cart_product }

  describe "PATCH #update" do
    it "generates the production sheet" do
      expect_any_instance_of(CartProductDesign).to receive(:some_method)
      patch :update, cart_product_design: {quantity: "20"}, cart_product_id: personalized_cart_product.id, id: cart_product_design , format: 'js'
    end
  end
end


class Admin::CartProductDesignsController < Admin::ApplicationController

  inherit_resources
  actions :create, :update, :destroy
  respond_to :html, :js

  def update
    @cart_product_design.some_method
    update! do |success, failure|
      success.html { redirect_to [:admin, @cart_product_design.order] }
      failure.html { redirect_to [:admin, @cart_product_design.order], alert: @cart_product_design.errors.full_messages.first }
    end
  end
end
```

This gives this error when I run rspec:

```
 1) Admin::CartProductDesignsController PATCH #update generates the production sheet
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
       Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: some_method
```

Why is it failing? 
Is somehow the patch request a blackbox which just returns some value and doesn't care what it's being called inside?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to tests rest html, not the method calling

Comment: The method I want to test doesn't generate any html.

Comment: then just test the result of the method's work

Comment: How is `@cart_product_design` being assigned prior to the reference in `update`?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I'm trying to test it in this way because it's more complicated to test the result. :some_method will regenerate a pdf, which is hard to test.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin it is assigned by inherited_resources, so basically it calls the "find" method.

Comment: @dioshari then just try to test wheigher the pdf is generated or not

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ yes, that's a possibility. However, I think is not the best one, because playing with weights it's a little bit dangerous.

Comment: @dioshari I believe that is exactly correct way, for me the check just to call ins't correct

Answer (score 1):

`@cart_product_design` is only set by the inherited `update!` method, so it should be `nil` when you call `some_method` on it in the first statement of your controller method. Is your method really called `some_method`?

To do what you want to do, see the README for the Inherited Resources gem and look for this example:

```
class ProjectsController < InheritedResources::Base
  def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.something_special!
    update!
  end
end
```

BTW, I assume you noticed that this gem is deprecated now.

Comment: then, how can I assert that my method is called?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure how can I mock it, since @cart_product_design is part of the controller than I'm calling.

Comment: Sorry for my original answer; I hadn't really looked at this gem at the time. See my revised answer.